replit run button installs unwanted python packages that break my project
Public replit:
https://replit.com/@mblakele/BugImportDecoupleHumps
When I run this replit, I see a poetry command that I haven't requested:
--> poetry add decouple humps
Using version ^0.0.7 for decouple
Using version ^0.2.2 for humps

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies...

Package operations: 2 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing decouple (0.0.7)
  • Installing humps (0.2.2)

Writing lock file

I think this is a result of replit upm searching for decouple and humps, which my pyproject.toml already specifies:
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
pyhumps = "3.8.*"
python-decouple = "^3.6.0"

But because replit guesses anyway, and gets it wrong about these packages, every run fails with:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/BugImportDecoupleHumps/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from decouple import config
ImportError: cannot import name 'config' from 'decouple' (/home/runner/BugImportDecoupleHumps/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/decouple/__init__.py)
 

After each attempt, I have to remove extraneous lines from my TOML and also use pip or upm to remove the bogus packages. If I do this, running the code from shell works ok:
~/BugImportDecoupleHumps$ pip uninstall decouple humps
Found existing installation: decouple 0.0.7
Uninstalling decouple-0.0.7:
  Would remove:
    /home/runner/BugImportDecoupleHumps/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/decouple-0.0.7.dist-info/*
    /home/runner/BugImportDecoupleHumps/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/decouple/*
Proceed (Y/n)? 
  Successfully uninstalled decouple-0.0.7
Found existing installation: humps 0.2.2
Uninstalling humps-0.2.2:
  Would remove:
    /home/runner/BugImportDecoupleHumps/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/humps-0.2.2.dist-info/*
    /home/runner/BugImportDecoupleHumps/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/humps/*
    /home/runner/BugImportDecoupleHumps/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tests/*
  Would not remove (might be manually added):
    /home/runner/BugImportDecoupleHumps/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/humps/__init__.pyi
    /home/runner/BugImportDecoupleHumps/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/humps/main.py
    /home/runner/BugImportDecoupleHumps/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/humps/main.pyi
    /home/runner/BugImportDecoupleHumps/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/humps/py.typed
Proceed (Y/n)? 
  Successfully uninstalled humps-0.2.2
~/BugImportDecoupleHumps$ python main.py 
hello False

How can I fix this? Can I stop replit from guessing about these packages?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Workaround:
Remove any unwanted packages. Run poetry install in the replit shell. Then add deliberately broken lines to pyproject.toml so that replit can’t run its own install.
[tool.poetry.dependencies] 
decouple = "^666.42.69" # replit bug workaround
humps = "^666.42.69" # replit bug workaround

This is crude but works around the problem within replit’s development environment. Remove the fake dependencies before deploying in other environments.

You can try running poetry remove python-decouple in the shell to the right of your main.py
According to poetry docs https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#remove
You can also use a --dry-run option if you are concerned

But I want python-decouple. It’s decouple that i don’t want, and the replit run button insists on adding it.

You added decouple instead of python-decouple or did something along the way where now both libraries are sitting in your .pythonlibs you can do poetry remove decouple python-decouple manually remove the files from your lib if you have to. then poetry cache clear pypi --all and then re-add your python-decouple with poetry add python-decouple Manually updating your TOML will not remove the packages in the .pythonlibs

No, i’ve removed decouple many times, from the toml and using pip. Replit adds it right back every time I use the run button. The proof is that it works ok from shell, as long as I avoid the run button.

Running okay from the shell would make sense if you are using python main.py because you did whatever you did using pip which installs the package in the global package directory instead of containing your packaging within the poetry virtual environment. If you use the run button from replit, it will use your poetry environment, which like I said has decouple AND python-decouple packages in the .pythonlibs directory

Ok but after rm -rf.pythonlibs and uninstalling the unwanted packages with pip, the run button still fails with the same error. Have you looked at the public replit I linked?

Yes I have. I recommend you remove anything you added with pip, run poetry remove on the packages you have inside of the poetry toml. You have to use poetry because the run button uses poetry. So run poetry cache clear pypi --all then run poetry install python-decouple humps. This will make sure you start fresh and just add what you need using poetry. Then confirm that there is are 2 packages that you see in the pythonlibs. Not literally 2 but there should only be reference to 2 packages humps and python-decouple. Then try again with the run button

I’ve done all that many times. Same error.
